# How do you validate your machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, random-forest, validation

I am wondering what approaches are commonly used for validating machine learning models designed for classification or prediction tasks:

Approaches that am using at the moment:

**Using truth-sets:** 
- ROCs, Bootstrapping, Accuracy, Sensitivity, Specificity, Cross-validation

**Orthogonal validation:** 
- Use a different class of algorithm that can perform prediction or classification task and compare results

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify the single most important thing to validate along with predictive discrimination (e.g., rank correlation between predicted and observed): calibration accuracy.  The calibration curve can be estimated nonparametrically using loess.  It is important that this demonstration of absolute predictive accuracy be done with high resolution, i.e., without binning predictions in any way.

If you have an independent holdout sample this is all easy to do.  Otherwise I recommend the optimism bootstrap to bias- (overfitting-) correct the apparent calibration curve to account for regression to the mean.  This is implemented for parametric models in the R `rms` package's `calibrate` function.

Sensitivity, specificity, and ROC curves do not play a role here, although in the simple binary $Y$ case the area under the ROC curve is a simple linear translation of a particular rank correlation measure: Somers' $D_{xy} = 2\times (c - \frac{1}{2})$ where the $c$-index is the ROC area in the simple case.

Comment: Thanks Frank for a great answer. Can you recommend an R package to do calibration accuracy ? Thanks again!

Comment: The R `rms` package `validate` and `calibrate` functions handle the usual regression models.  If you have an independent sample validation, the `val.prob` function does this.

Comment: My current model is based on RF.  
Thanks again, Frank - big help!

Comment: So if you get predicted probabilities from RF you can use `val.prob` for independent sample validation or as part of a  cross-validation loop.

Comment: How are you planning on obtained calibrated results from a RF? lots of people present risk models from RF, but still unclear to me if this makes sense. These people believe you can (but they don't know how to create a high resolution calibration curve?): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21915433

Comment: Getting risk predictions from RF is done frequently, and makes sense.

Comment: @FrankHarrell If you have any readings you'd suggest they would be much appreciated. Berk *Statistical Learning from a Regression Perspective* seemed set against using probabilities. J Kruppa has published a fair amount in support of using the probabilities, but never considers imbalanced data or makes a clear distinction between calibration/discrimination.

Comment: I would never dream of not using probabilities.  They capture close calls and minor errors, as opposed to the all-or-nothing classification approach.  They also lead us to consider proper scoring rules so that one optimizes the right criterion.  I don't have a single best reference on the subject - perhaps an article in JASA on proper scoring rules - but this is covered in a multitude of places.